# Cron not working

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, cron, transactional-mail

I have installed a new `Magento installation 1.9.3.4` with installatron, all the other shops I made I did it manually via FTP but this one I did through Installatron.

The problem that i got is that the **order e-mails won't be send...**

I tried every cron option I can imagine and even the hosting company doesn't know it. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your cron tab properly.

Login in to your Linux server and enter command `crontab -l` you can see cron jobs there, if not create a new cron tab.
If its there check your `cron.php` or `cron.sh` is called properly in cron tab

Below links may help you to set the cron tabs in Linux server/cpanel

[Link 1](https://blog.amasty.com/configure-magento-cron-job/)

[Link 2](http://www.magentodeveloperleedsuk.co.uk/setting-up-magento-cron-jobs-via-ssh-command-line/)