# Emails not being sent when new orders are placed

Tags: order-email, magento2.1.6

This is what I've done so far

```
 - I've already configured the store's sales email to the correct email addresses
 - Test smtp (send test email)
```

My mailgun configuration works properly. Email were being fired when a user subscribe, etc.

It seems that this problem occurs when a new order is placed.

Because when I view sales>orders and then view a certain order and click "send email" the email is being sent.

Can anyone help me debug this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be because of the cron job, you have to set the cron job properly to run every minute. I have answered in a different post how to debug the cron tab.

LINK - [Cron not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192786/cron-not-working/195507#195507)

To run a Magento2 cron job, use this command

```
****** /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Magento2/bin/magento cron:run
```

**/usr/bin/php** and path to Magento will be different  for different servers.

Comment: Hi Mr. Rinto, I've followed the tutorial but I don't have cron.sh on my root directory? which file should I target for the cron?

Comment: Just updated my answer.